# Problems rendering markdown with python-markdown-math

Tags: python, math, markdown, mathjax

I'm trying to figure out how to render markdown syntax in a similar way than Math StackExchange site. I want it to do with a python library instead of any sort of command line tool.

After a lot of researching I've found [markdown](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown) and [python-markdown-math](https://github.com/mitya57/python-markdown-math), so I've decided to go with them. To use both I've just installed them like:

- `pip install markdown`
- `pip install python-markdown-math`

That said, let's start by analizing a little example of the output generated by the math stackexchange site:

[image]

And now, let's try to achieve a similar result using `markdown` and `python-markdown-math` libraries:

```
import textwrap
import markdown
from pathlib import Path

src = """\
Rendered result of `$a+b$` ==> $a+b$

Rendered result of `$$a+b$$` ==> $$a+b$$
"""

md = markdown.Markdown(
    extensions=['mdx_math'],
    extension_configs={
        'mdx-math': {'enable_dollar_delimiter': True}
    }
)
html = """\
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>MathJax example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
{}
</body>
</html>
""".format(md.convert(src))

Path('test.html').write_text(html)
```

If we run that snippet and then open the generated `test.html` we'll see the rendered html will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>MathJax example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Rendered result of <code>$a+b$</code> ==&gt; $a+b$</p>
<p>Rendered result of <code>$$a+b$$</code> ==&gt; <script type="math/tex; mode=display">a+b</script>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the result is pretty much different than what I'd like to get, so my question is, how do I get a correct rendered html (like math stackexchange site)?

Comment: I'm not sure what result did you expect to get. The documentation clearly says that this extension relies on the [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) JS-library for all the heavy lifting. The extension itself is pretty simple, it just transforms the Markdown syntax into the one compatible with the MathJax. It would help if you specify the "expected result" beyond the "_As you can see the `$a+b$` is not being rendered correctly._"

Comment: @SergGr Mmm, I thought by seeing the outcome of the second example `$$a+b$$` => `<script type="math/tex; mode=display">a+b</script>` it was clear than `$a+$b` hasn't been rendered... I've taken a snapshot from the math stackexchange site

Comment: I believe you missed the point. The way that extension works is that it renders an HTML that can be **_post-processed on the client side_** by the  MathJax JS-library to convert it into a real output. It never claimed to do all the rendering on the server-side. So given that I repeat my question, why do you treat that result as not expect and what is the expected result?

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLY8R.png) of how I see some random [math.se] question ([link to the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087663/show-that-cos-has-at-least-one-zeropoint)) with JS disabled in my browser. You can see that the result is not yet rendered and it is supposed to be rendered by the same MathJax library on the client side.

Comment: @SergGr I've changed completely the body of my question, please let me know if my goal is now much clearer with this new content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in comments the library you use is a thin wrapper that converts Markdown into a format compatible with the [MathJax JS-library](https://www.mathjax.org/).

If you are OK with the final rendering performed on the client-side as the SO really does, you need to load and configure the MathJax in your page. You need to read details of the configuration in the documentation of the MathJax [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html) and [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/config-files.html#combined-configurations). Some (non-minimal) configuration that made your example work for me is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {
            inlineMath: [["$", "$"], ["\\\\(", "\\\\)"]],
            displayMath: [["$$", "$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"]],
            processEscapes: true
        },
        config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
        jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS", "output/NativeMML"],
        extensions: ["MathMenu.js", "MathZoom.js"]
    });
</script>
```

It is probably a bad configuration, just an example. I strongly recommend you to read the actual documentation and decide how to properly configure it for your case.

If you want to do full server-side rendering, MathJax claims that it can be run under the NodeJS but I haven't tried that.

Comment: @SerGr Ok, I've tried pasting your snippet directly in the html code and now I understand what you said in your comments a little bit more, before validating let me play for few minutes with it to see if I'm able to generate the right html directly with my python snippet. Btw, any idea how to render the code blocks like SO as well? ie: `$a+b$` & `$$a+b$$` , +1 in the meantime

Comment: @BPL, sorry I'm not really a Markdown specialist so don't know if this is a standard feature or some extension. Also if you are not able to generate the proper output it might be because of a wrong configuration. My configuration is not perfect, it is just a random example that works on that particular example. You may also try to look at the actual configuration [math.se] uses.

Comment: Ok, I've validated your answer in the code and it does the job... next will be figure out this stuff with code blocks... and I'll pretty much be done here :) . Thanks for your help